How to avoid code duplication between DTOs when one extends another with an ID property and a relationship model that's a bit different
I have a domain entity KycInformation and I'm using two DTOs to handle different scenarios:

KycInformationDto for create operations (no ID needed)
KycInformationDetailDto for get/update operations (includes ID)

The only differences between these DTOs are:

KycInformationDetailDto includes an Id property
Documents collection uses KycDocumentDetailDto instead of KycDocumentDto

What would be the best approach to reduce this code duplication while maintaining the separation between create and get/update DTOs? I'm using AutoMapper for mapping between these types.
public class KycInformation : BaseEntity
{
    public required KycStatus Status { get; set; }
    public required RiskRating RiskRating { get; set; }
    public required AmlStatus AmlStatus { get; set; }
    public required SanctionsCheckStatus SanctionsCheckStatus { get; set; }
    public string? ComplianceNotes { get; set; }
    public string? ParentCompany { get; set; }

    public required Guid LegalEntityId { get; set; }
    public required LegalEntity LegalEntity { get; set; }

    public ICollection<KycDocument> Documents { get; set; } = new List<KycDocument>();

    public void AddDocument(KycDocument document) => Documents.Add(document);

    public void ClearDocuments() => Documents.Clear();
}

public record KycInformationDto
{
    public required KycStatus Status { get; init; }
    public required RiskRating RiskRating { get; init; }
    public required AmlStatus AmlStatus { get; init; }
    public required SanctionsCheckStatus SanctionsCheckStatus { get; init; }
    public string? ComplianceNotes { get; init; }
    public string? ParentCompany { get; init; }

    public ICollection<KycDocumentDto> Documents { get; init; } = new List<KycDocumentDto>();

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<KycInformation, KycInformationDto>();
            CreateMap<KycInformationDto, KycInformation>();
        }
    }
}

public record KycInformationDetailDto : KycInformationDto
{
    public required Guid Id { get; init; }

    public new ICollection<KycDocumentDetailDto> Documents { get; init; } = new List<KycDocumentDetailDto>();

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<KycInformation, KycInformationDetailDto>();
            CreateMap<KycInformationDetailDto, KycInformation>();
        }
    }
}

public record KycDocumentDto
{
    public required string DocumentType { get; init; }
    public required string DocumentName { get; init; }
    public string? DocumentDescription { get; init; }
    public required string DocumentUrl { get; init; }

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<KycDocument, KycDocumentDto>();
            CreateMap<KycDocumentDto, KycDocument>();
        }
    }
}

public record KycDocumentDetailDto : KycDocumentDto
{
    public required Guid Id { get; init; }

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<KycDocument, KycDocumentDetailDto>();
            CreateMap<KycDocumentDetailDto, KycDocument>();
        }
    }
}


Why are you using two DTOs to begin with? And how are you actually storing them? Is there a real reason or are you trying to follow some "best practices" article? You don't need AutoMapper or two DTOs to work with EF Core.

If you use EF, then creations does need an ID or rather, a primary key to be configured. EF Core doesn't store entities one by one, it will persist all pending changes when SaveChanges is called and fill all auto-generated IDs and FK values in all entities.

An actual reason to have two different entities is because one is used in a read-only and one in an edit scenario, eg one for reporting and one for data entry/editing. Usually you need different properties, different shapes and different rules for reporting and editing. In fact, you may have two different DbContexts, one read-only with tracking disabled for the reporting scenario and one with it enabled for the edit scenario. That's the opposite of what you described. In both cases you need a primary key.

I had a similar situation; which also had a "class progression". It starts with a "relation" that may or may not require a "calculation". The calculation uses the same properties as the relation; and adds others. Instead of inheritance, or using separate classes, I used "composition". The relation instance is added to the calculation as a component; making it "complete". In your case, you could just have an "Id component" with a reference to the (original) DTO. The DTO can be "detached" later if need be.

If dealing with "two" references turns one off, then using "re-direction" solves that; e.g. public string Foo => component.Foo;

@PanagiotisKanavos, sorry for the late reply, and good point.

In my opinion using the composition approach will be right choice which will help you avoid or reduce the duplication, so you do not need to create separate DTOs for create and update. and you are using EF Core it will manage id by its own. When you call SaveChanges, EF Core will handle ID assignment, so you not need to create a separate DTO just to exclude the Id.use public Guid? Id => IdComponent.Id; so you do not need to create separate types.
I have prepared sample demo:
KycInformationController.cs:
using KycInformationApi.DTOs;
using KycInformationApi.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace KycInformationApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class KycInformationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly KycInformationService _service;

        public KycInformationController(KycInformationService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(KycInformationDto), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<KycInformationDto>> CreateKyc([FromBody] KycInformationDto dto)
        {
            var createdKyc = await _service.CreateKycAsync(dto);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetKycById), new { id = createdKyc.Id }, createdKyc);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(KycInformationDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<KycInformationDto>> GetKycById(Guid id)
        {
            var kyc = await _service.GetKycByIdAsync(id);
            if (kyc == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(kyc);
        }

    }

}

IdComponent.cs:
namespace KycInformationApi.DTOs
{
    public record IdComponent
    {
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    }


    public record KycInformationDto
    {
        public IdComponent IdComponent { get; init; } = new IdComponent();
        public required KycStatus Status { get; init; }
        public required RiskRating RiskRating { get; init; }
        public required AmlStatus AmlStatus { get; init; }
        public required SanctionsCheckStatus SanctionsCheckStatus { get; init; }
        public string? ComplianceNotes { get; init; }
        public string? ParentCompany { get; init; }
        public ICollection<KycDocumentDto> Documents { get; init; } = new List<KycDocumentDto>();

        public Guid? Id => IdComponent.Id;
    }

    public record KycDocumentDto
    {
        public required string DocumentType { get; init; }
        public required string DocumentName { get; init; }
        public string? DocumentDescription { get; init; }
        public required string DocumentUrl { get; init; }
    }

}

KycInformation.cs:
namespace KycInformationApi.Models
{
    public class KycInformation
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public required KycStatus Status { get; set; }
        public required RiskRating RiskRating { get; set; }
        public required AmlStatus AmlStatus { get; set; }
        public required SanctionsCheckStatus SanctionsCheckStatus { get; set; }
        public string? ComplianceNotes { get; set; }
        public string? ParentCompany { get; set; }
        public ICollection<KycDocument> Documents { get; set; } = new List<KycDocument>();
    }

    public class KycDocument
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public required string DocumentType { get; set; }
        public required string DocumentName { get; set; }
        public string? DocumentDescription { get; set; }
        public required string DocumentUrl { get; set; }
    }

}

KycInformationRepository.cs:
using KycInformationApi.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace KycInformationApi.Repositories
{
    public class KycInformationRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public KycInformationRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task AddAsync(KycInformation kycInformation)
        {
            _context.KycInformations.Add(kycInformation);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<KycInformation?> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
        {
            return await _context.KycInformations
                .Include(k => k.Documents)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(k => k.Id == id);
        }
    }

}

KycInformationService.cs:
using AutoMapper;
using KycInformationApi.DTOs;
using KycInformationApi.Models;
using KycInformationApi.Repositories;

namespace KycInformationApi.Services
{
    public class KycInformationService
    {
        private readonly KycInformationRepository _repository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public KycInformationService(KycInformationRepository repository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<KycInformationDto> CreateKycAsync(KycInformationDto dto)
        {
            var kycEntity = _mapper.Map<KycInformation>(dto);
            await _repository.AddAsync(kycEntity);

            // Retrieve saved entity with ID and map back to DTO
            return _mapper.Map<KycInformationDto>(kycEntity);
        }

        public async Task<KycInformationDto?> GetKycByIdAsync(Guid id)
        {
            var kycEntity = await _repository.GetByIdAsync(id);
            return kycEntity == null ? null : _mapper.Map<KycInformationDto>(kycEntity);
        }
    }

}

ApplicationDbContext.cs:
using KycInformationApi.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace KycInformationApi
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<KycInformation> KycInformations { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<KycDocument> KycDocuments { get; set; } = null!;

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<KycInformation>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<KycDocument>().HasKey(d => d.Id);
        }
    }

}

KycMappingProfile.cs:
using AutoMapper;
using KycInformationApi.DTOs;
using KycInformationApi.Models;

namespace KycInformationApi
{
    public class KycMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public KycMappingProfile()
        {
            // Map between KycInformation and KycInformationDto, including reverse mapping
            CreateMap<KycInformation, KycInformationDto>()
                .ForPath(dest => dest.IdComponent.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ReverseMap();

            // Map between KycDocument and KycDocumentDto, including reverse mapping
            CreateMap<KycDocument, KycDocumentDto>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using KycInformationApi.Repositories;
using KycInformationApi.Services;
using KycInformationApi;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using KycInformationApi.DTOs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers()
     .AddJsonOptions(options =>
     {
         options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter());
     });
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Register services
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("KycDb"));
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(KycMappingProfile));
builder.Services.AddScoped<KycInformationRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<KycInformationService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

// Seed data
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<KycInformationService>();

    // Example usage: Creating and retrieving KYC info
    var newKyc = new KycInformationDto
    {
        Status = KycStatus.Active,
        RiskRating = RiskRating.Medium,
        AmlStatus = AmlStatus.Clear,
        SanctionsCheckStatus = SanctionsCheckStatus.None,
        ComplianceNotes = "Initial compliance review",
        ParentCompany = "Example Corp",
        Documents = new List<KycDocumentDto>
        {
            new KycDocumentDto
            {
                DocumentType = "ID",
                DocumentName = "Passport",
                DocumentUrl = "http://example.com/doc.pdf"
            }
        }
    };

  
    var createdKyc = await service.CreateKycAsync(newKyc);

    var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    logger.LogInformation("Created KYC ID: {Id}", createdKyc.Id);
}



app.Run();

So, in above code KycInformationService handles mapping between DTOs and entities.KycInformationRepository added logic which handle create and fetch by id for KycInformation.KycMappingProfile we have configures AutoMapper to handle mappings between DTOs and models with reverse mapping enabled.



The MapFrom for Documents is not needed.

@LucianBargaoanu thank you for your suggestion. i agree and updated code as well. :)

Thank you for the reply. The reason I needed two DTOs in the first place was to avoid asking users to fill in the "id" fields during creation, as it doesn't look good. However, for edits, we need to specify documentIds, so you know how to map them together.  So, I’m not entirely sure I understand your point.

@nop In my provided code, by using Guid? Id, there’s no need for the user to supply an ID when creating a record. EF Core will automatically generate and populate the ID in the response DTO after saving the record.
For update or get operations, however, the ID is required to fetch or update the existing record, which is expected behavior.

I understand your initial approach with two DTOs, but in my code I focus on duplicate code while keeping the DTOs simple. If you’d like to make sure that users don’t see or provide an ID during creation, you could achieve this by either:

Specifying in the API documentation which fields are required for each operation, or
Adding validation logic to enforce the absence of the ID for create operations.
let me know if you still have any question or concern regarding provided information

